# PHP code - converting two dimensional arrays to one dimensional array $ vector - functions toVector and toArray - how to do it?

Tags: php, arrays, function, vector

My Homework to do:
Using PHP (or any other language) without any additional libraries, please write two functions:

- toVector ($ table) - converting a two-dimensional array $ table (example table below) to a one-dimensional array $ vector (without data loss, the example below) and returning it at the output
- toTable ($ vector, $ m, $ n) - converting a one-dimensional array $ vector to a two-dimensional array $ table size $ n to $ m

  ```
  $ vowelTable = array (
   array ('a', 'e', ​​'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'),
   array ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y'),
  );

  $ vowelVector = array (
   'a', 'e', ​​'i', 'o', 'u', 'y', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y',
  );
  ```

and now

PHP functions -

```
function toVector(array $array) {
    $elements = [];
    foreach($array as $row) {
        $elements = array_merge($elements, $row);
    }
    return $elements;
}

function toArray(array $vector, int $m) {
    return array_chunk($vector, $m);
}
```

and how to implement, what is next? I am just such a beginner, I don't know a lot of stuff.

Comment: Your code is working fine.

Comment: Shouldn'y `toArray()` have another parameter - `toTable ($ vector, $ m, $ n)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks just fine, if you want to implement it, you could just create an array and test it using print_r. Such as:

```
<?php
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
?>
```